# reason: 'missing revert data in call exception' - Alchemy provider and ethers

Tags: ethers.js, rinkeby, web3-providers

I am following Alchemy tutorial and i keep getting errors when im trying to interact with my smart contract. any suggestion why?
I keep getting the error:

reason: 'missing revert data in call exception',

here is the code:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers")

const contract = require("./../truffle/build/contracts/SmartLock.json")
// Provider
const alchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(
  "rinkeby",
  "https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/H37H7-VmBjLl2KTsn1QauJmgoE55CTJK"
)

// Signer
const signer = new ethers.Wallet("PRIVATE_KEY", alchemyProvider)

// Contract
const shelfContract = new ethers.Contract(
  "0xa5765dba029EB0EfCDfBE560705B9c181eb77928",
  contract.abi,
  signer
)

// Mint
async function main() {
  try {
    const tx = await shelfContract.mint(
      "0xF0E8F7C818Ed70189D43f0e53E2aB4390e7Ab114", // owner public key
      1234,
      1,
      1
    )
    await tx.wait()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  try {
    const owner = await shelfContract.isItemAvailable(1234)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
main()
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this means that (a) a smart contract transaction is reverting with an EVM error, and (b) ethers.js has a bug in how it's handling that error, so that instead of producing the expected error in JS, it's failing in some unexpected way.